# MVC 6 Configuration Validation

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

In an MVC 6 project, I have the following configuration file...

```
{
  "ServiceSettings" :
  {
    "Setting1" : "Value"
  }
}
```

...and the following class...

```
public class ServiceSettings
{
  public Setting1
  {
    get;

    set;
  }
}
```

In the `ConfigureServices` method of the `Startup` class, I have added the following line of code...

```
services.Configure<ServiceSettings>(Configuration.GetConfigurationSection("ServiceSettings"));
```

If the value of `Setting1` is required, how do I validate this?  I could validate at the point the `IOptions<ServiceSettings>` instance is actually used but if the value of `Setting1` is necessary for the operation of the service, I would like to catch this as early as possible instead of further downstream.  The old `ConfigurationSection` object let you specify rules that would throw exceptions at the point the configuration data was read if something was invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went and stuck `[Required]` over any mandatory properties in `ServiceSettings`and added the following in `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
services.Configure<ServiceSettings>(settings =>
{
    ConfigurationBinder.Bind(Configuration.GetSection("ServiceSettings"), settings);

    EnforceRequiredStrings(settings);
})
```

And the following to `Startup`:

```
private static void EnforceRequiredStrings(object options)
{
    var properties = options.GetType().GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties.Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string));
    var requiredProperties = properties.Where(p => p.CustomAttributes.Any(a => a.AttributeType == typeof(RequiredAttribute)));

    foreach (var property in requiredProperties)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)property.GetValue(options)))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(property.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have marked your solution as the answer because it is similar to what I came up with (before I read your solution).  I opted for implementing the IValidatableObject interface as opposed to attributes.  In this scenario, this is probably more of a preference than anything.

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like the following:

```
services.Configure<ServiceSettings>(serviceSettings =>
{
    // bind the newed-up type with the data from the configuration section
    ConfigurationBinder.Bind(serviceSettings, Configuration.GetConfigurationSection(nameof(ServiceSettings)));

    // modify/validate these settings if you want to
});

// your settings should be available through DI now
```

Comment: I marked the other solution as the answer although your solution was correct.  I would have marked both as answers if I could have.  Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 2):

### Clean way to validate options with ASP.Net-Core 2.0

From `netcore2.0` onwards, `PostConfigure` is a good fit. This function takes a configuration delegate too, but is executed last, so everything is already configured.

```
// Configure options as usual
services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("section"));

// Then, immediately afterwards define a delegate to validate the FINAL options later
services.PostConfigure<MyOptions>(myOptions => {
    // Take the fully configured myOptions and run validation checks...
    if (myOptions.Option1 == null) {
        throw new Exception("Option1 has to be specified");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If not afraid of adding more code to configuration objects, there are possibilities to implement validation upon startup like described in [Andrew Lock blog](https://andrewlock.net/adding-validation-to-strongly-typed-configuration-objects-in-asp-net-core/). He created NuGet package to avoid adding code yourself.
If you want to explore more possibilities, there is also [ConfigurationValidation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ConfigurationValidation/) package providing some extended configuration validation functionality (opinionated: I am author).
If you are using FluentValidation for something, [there is possibility](https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2020/april/validate-configurations-with-fluentvalidation-in-aspnet-core/) to use it for configuration validation as well.